# Is SignalR group message is broadcast to all connected users?

Tags: c#, signalr

According to the [documentations](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups)

> the server does not maintain lists of groups or group memberships

So as I may understand from this quote, the groups are maintained on the client side.
That is to say, when adding a user to a group, he gets notified about that and saves internally (at client side) a list of groups he is being in.

If that is true, when sending a message to group, it sends it to all connected users and the filtering is done on the client side.

Does it true? Anyone knows how it works internally?

Comment: Yes, SignalR sends message to all connected users. If you want to send message to specfic user, you need to custom SignalR connection.

Comment: You mean, group message sends to all connected users?

Comment: Yes, it'll send message to all connected users

Comment: Great you answered my question, thank you. You can post it as an answer so other viewers will know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, SignalR sends message to all connected users. If you want to send message to specfic user, you need to customize SignalR connection.

Comment: I don't think that this is true. Group state is maintained on a connection level on the server side:
A signalr connection has a list of associated groups. On a signalr node, a list of connections for a group is maintained, but this list is not progagated to all nodes of the signalr cluster, meaning that you cannot get a list of all connections belonging to a group.
If a message is sent to a group, it is sent to all connections of that group.

Comment: Do you have some source/proof this is actually what's going on?

Comment: https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups reading the overview. Imagine what it would mean for scalability if every message went to every connection.

Comment: signalr does not propagate group membership across signalr nodes for scalability, so on 2 nodes, there is a list of connections for a group on every node.

Comment: Please see my statement. It's written that SignalR sends message to all connected users. If you need to send message to specific user/group of user, you need to customize SignalR.

Comment: The first statement in the overview section: "Groups in SignalR provide a method for broadcasting messages to specified subsets of connected clients.".  So, no, a group message is not sent to all connected users and you do not need to customize signalR.